# SC StartService Failed 1053 while running a batch file as a service

Tags: batch-file, windows-services, servicecontroller

I'm trying to run my batch file(run.bat) as a windows service using Service controller

This is the command I used to create my Service

```
sc \\myservername create myservicename binPath="C:\Program Files\Directories to use\ANI\run.bat" start=auto

[SC] CreateService SUCCESS
```

When I run my service:

```
sc start ANIService
[SC] StartService Failed 1053:
The service did not respond to the start or control request in the timely fashion
```

Comment: If you replace `"C:\Program Files\Directories to use\ANI\run.bat"` with a batch file that just prints `echo %1` do you get the same error? If not, your problem is with `"C:\Program Files\Directories to use\ANI\run.bat"`.

Comment: @LinuxDisciple: no, the whole idea is wrong.  A service is an executable that implements a particular interface, you can't just tell the operating system that a batch file is a service and expect it to work.  (The batch file might or might not run, but because it doesn't call StartServiceCtrlDispatcher, you'll still get the "did not respond" error either way.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/), this should work fine.